# SQL script to create a database using a variable name

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, scripting, ddl

I'm trying to create a generic script to create a database and want to pass the database name as a variable; but it's not working.

Here is my code so far

```
DECLARE @ID sysname; 

SET @ID = 'test'
SET @ID = QUOTENAME(@ID)

CREATE DATABASE @ID

ON  PRIMARY
( NAME = [' + @ID + '], FILENAME =  N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\' +@ID+ '.mdf' , SIZE = 211968KB ,
 MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
   LOG ON 
( NAME = [' + @ID + '_log'], FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'@ID + '_log.ldf' , SIZE = 149696KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

which gives me the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@ID'.

Comment: I take it that it's rather _not_ working? :}

Comment: yes not working (sorry), it gives error "Incorrect syntax near '@ID'."

Comment: Welcome to SO, BTW. :}  What would help your question(s), is to provide a specific error message you've encountered, what you've tried to no avail etcetera.  It will save those who would seek to help you from having to run what you've provided to see the error themselves, possibly see a different error or no error in their environment, and generally reduce friction to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use SQLCMD mode in SSMS (*SQLCMD Mode* in the *Query* menu) or execute your script with `sqlcmd.exe`, you can use a [SQLCMD scripting variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx):

```
:setvar ID "test"

CREATE DATABASE [$(ID)]

ON PRIMARY ( NAME = ['$(ID)_Primary'], FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\$(ID).mdf' , SIZE = 211968KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) LOG ON ( NAME = ['$(ID)_log'], FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\$(ID)_log.ldf' , SIZE = 149696KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

From the command line, you would need to comment out the `:setvar ID "test"` statement (i.e. `--:setvar ID "test"`) and run the script like so...

```
sqlcmd.exe -E -i YourScript.sql -v ID="real"
```

...assuming Windows authentication, a local, default instance of SQL Server, and `YourScript.sql` in the current directory.

*The key* is the `-v` command-line option to specify the name of the SQLCMD variable you wish to set and its value.

Using a SQLCMD variable like this is essentially what [SSDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) does under the hood.

Comment: I'm trying to create in the same way, a login with access to datatabse that have the same variable name, but I'm getting error..please help , my code is      USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO $(ID); 
GO the error is Incorrect syntax near '.'.